# Admob interstitial ads issue?

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial, drawer

I am making a simple app, in this app I am add a navigation drawer & drawer item have contain website url link when I click navigation item it was open another brawser with url that I have given & I am put google admob ads in this app so when I click on this item page was open with admob interstitial ads nice but my problem is when ad was shown I am click back button ad was close & again my app is open but I want to shown that page (my url shown in browser) but it now happen again open my app when I close the admob interstitial ads. How to fix that pronlem, please any one help me.

watch video for better understand : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8YTgurIRbm5SS01YW1WRHptYlU

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

<supports-screens
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo_circle"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".SpleshScreen.SpleshScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".Messaging.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
        android:noHistory="true"/>

</application>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question, it doesn't make sense and your video doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the adListner() for the ads, put this in your code after you initialize your Interstitial Code

```
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(mContext.getString(R.string.admob_ad_unit_id_interstitial));
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().
                build());

mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                super.onAdClosed();

                // perform your task after the ad is closed
                Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentAct.this, GoToAct.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                // load the ad again if you need to show it again
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().
                        build());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
            }
        });

// open your ad
btnclick(){

    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        // if your ad is not ready to be shown, perform your task here
        Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentAct.this, GoToAct.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```